# How do I get the output to repeat all lines of the data from this txt?

Tags: java, arrays, string, format

I have a list of data in a text file and I would like to format the data differently using eclipse. So far I have

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ReadingWeather {
public static void main(String[] args)

        throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input=new Scanner(new File("Jetport2013.txt"));

    String x = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(x);
    String y = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(y);
    String z = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(z);
    int count=0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;

    }

    double[] precip = new double[count];
    double[] snow = new double[count];
    double[] snowDepth = new double[count];
    double[] tempMin = new double[count];
    double[] tempMax = new double[count];

    x = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(x);
    y = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(y);

    count=0;
    input.close();
    Scanner scanner2=new Scanner(System.in);
    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        input.next();
        input.next();
        precip[count]=scanner2.nextDouble();
        snow[count]=scanner2.nextDouble();
        snowDepth[count]=scanner2.nextDouble();
        tempMax[count]=scanner2.nextDouble();
        tempMin[count]=scanner2.nextDouble();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(arrayAvg(precip));
    System.out.println(arrayAvg(snow));
    System.out.println(arrayAvg(snowDepth));
    System.out.println(arrayAvg(tempMin));
    System.out.println(arrayAvg(tempMax));
}

public static double arrayAvg(double a[]) {
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        count++;
        if (a[i] != 393.7){
            sum += a[i];
        }
    }
    return sum/count;
}

public static double tempConvert(int n){
    double celsius = (n / 10.0)* 9 / 5 + 32;
    return celsius;
}
public static double snowConvert(int n) {
    double snowInches = n * 0.03937;

    return snowInches;
}

public static double precipitationConvert(int n) {
    double rainInches = ((n*0.03937)/10);
    return rainInches;
}
```

}

which gives me my column headings and my first line of data. How do I get it to repeat to show all of the data? and how would I edit the date column to read in "MM/DD/YYYY" format instead of "YYYYMMDD" like it is in the text file?

Comment: Can you give an example input and output?

Comment: An [MCVE] would be best

Comment: `while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;

    }`: this is an infinite loop: you never go to the next line into the loop, and thus are infinitely checking if there is a next line after your three header lines. This information should be in the question: you can't possibly have missed the fact that your program never ended. And using your debugger would have make the reason obvious.